# When I want to add a new point to the collection, should I create it from scratch?

Tags: python, database, vector-database, qdrant, qdrantclient

I started using qdrant today, I am very new to this subject.

I am working on similarity search in images and I added my images to qdrant, but later when I want to add other images to my database, it deletes the existing one and creates a new database, so I lose my old images.

Can I add as many images as I want to my existing collection at any time, can you help me with this? I share my code with you.
Thank you for your interest

```
class ImageEmbedding:

def image_to_database(self):

    base_directory = "Images"
    all_image_urls = os.listdir(base_directory)

    sample_image_urls = all_image_urls
    sample_image_urls = list(map(lambda item: f"{base_directory}/{item}",sample_image_urls))

    payloads = DataFrame.from_records({"image_url": sample_image_urls})
    payloads["model_id"] = 2

    images = list(map(lambda el:Image.open(el),payloads["image_url"]))

    target_width = 256

    def resize_image(image_url):
        pil_image = Image.open(image_url)
        image_aspect_ratio = pil_image.width / pil_image.height
        resized_pil_image = pil_image.resize([target_width,math.floor(target_width * image_aspect_ratio)])
        return resized_pil_image

    def convert_image_to_base64(pil_image):
        image_data = BytesIO()
        pil_image.save(image_data,format="JPEG")
        base64_string = base64.b64encode(image_data.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
        return base64_string

    resized_images = list(map(lambda el: resize_image(el), sample_image_urls))
    base64_strings = list(map(lambda el: convert_image_to_base64(el), resized_images))
    payloads["base64"] = base64_strings

    processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/resnet-50")
    model = ResNetForImageClassification.from_pretrained("microsoft/resnet-50")

    inputs = processor(images,return_tensors="pt",)
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    embeddings = outputs.logits

    embedding_length = len(embeddings[0])

    load_dotenv()

    qclient = QdrantClient(
        url = os.getenv('QDRANT_DB_URL'),
        api_key = os.getenv('QDRANT_API_KEY'),
    )

    collection_name = "die_models_images"

    collection = qclient.recreate_collection(
        collection_name=collection_name,
        vectors_config=VectorParams(
            size=embedding_length,
            distance=Distance.COSINE
        )
    )

    payload_dicts = payloads.to_dict(orient="records")

    records = [
        models.Record(
            id=idx,
            payload=payload_dicts[idx],
            vector=embeddings[idx]
        )
        for idx, _ in  enumerate(payload_dicts)
    ]

    qclient.upload_records(
        collection_name=collection_name,
        records=records
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `recreate_collection`, which will delete and create the specified collection every time it is invoked.

Instead, you probably want to use `create_collection` and only call it once:

```py
collection = qclient.create_collection(
    collection_name=collection_name,
    vectors_config=VectorParams(
        size=embedding_length,
        distance=Distance.COSINE
    )
)
```

You must also make sure to use unique IDs for each record you insert.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I put this part in the comment line
`  
collection = qclient.recreate_collection(
            collection_name=collection_name,
            vectors_config=VectorParams(
                size=embedding_length,
                distance=Distance.COSINE
            )
        )
`
The problem persists, deleting old data and adding new ones

Comment: Please also make sure you use unique IDs for records you insert. Right now you always enumerate from the same ID, overwriting old ones. If you don't care about the ID, you can use random UUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `recreate_collection` instead of `create_collection`.
Do not call the `create_collection` multiple times or wrap it in a try except statement as a work around because it will throw an exception if a collection with that name already exists.
I would suggest you do it this way :

```
import datetime

class ImageEmbedding:

def image_to_database(self):
    
    base_directory = "Images"
    all_image_urls = os.listdir(base_directory)
    
    sample_image_urls = all_image_urls
    sample_image_urls = list(map(lambda item: f"{base_directory}/{item}", sample_image_urls))
    
    payloads = DataFrame.from_records({"image_url": sample_image_urls})
    payloads["model_id"] = 2
    
    images = list(map(lambda el:Image.open(el), payloads["image_url"]))
    
    target_width = 256
    
    def resize_image(image_url):
        pil_image = Image.open(image_url)
        image_aspect_ratio = pil_image.width / pil_image.height
        resized_pil_image = pil_image.resize([target_width, math.floor(target_width * image_aspect_ratio)])
        return resized_pil_image
    
    def convert_image_to_base64(pil_image):
        image_data = BytesIO()
        pil_image.save(image_data, format="JPEG")
        base64_string = base64.b64encode(image_data.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
        return base64_string
    
    resized_images = list(map(lambda el: resize_image(el), sample_image_urls))
    base64_strings = list(map(lambda el: convert_image_to_base64(el), resized_images))
    payloads["base64"] = base64_strings
    
    processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/resnet-50")
    model = ResNetForImageClassification.from_pretrained("microsoft/resnet-50")
    
    inputs = processor(images, return_tensors="pt")
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    embeddings = outputs.logits
    
    embedding_length = len(embeddings[0])
    
    qclient = QdrantClient(
        url=os.getenv('QDRANT_DB_URL'),
        api_key=os.getenv('QDRANT_API_KEY'),
    )
    
    collection_name = "die_models_images"
    
    collection = qclient.create_collection(
        collection_name=collection_name,
        vectors_config=VectorParams(
            size=embedding_length,
            distance=Distance.COSINE
        )
    )
    
    payload_dicts = payloads.to_dict(orient="records")
    
    records = []
    for idx, _ in enumerate(payload_dicts):
        unique_id = int(str(idx) + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
        record = models.Record(
            id=unique_id,
            payload=payload_dicts[idx],
            vector=embeddings[idx]
        )
        records.append(record)
    
    qclient.upload_records(
        collection_name=collection_name,
        records=records
    )
```